# How to fix header in Ant design table version 3?

Tags: css, reactjs, antd

In ant design verison 3, I'm using table component and I tried to give position:sticky to thead > th.

But it's not working.

This feature is already implemented in Ant version 4. But it will be a long to migrate version.

Is there any way I can fix this ?

I tried to give position:sticky to thead > th.

This didn't help in solving the issue

Expected to make table header sticky

Answer (score 1):

You need in `position: sticky` for `thead` element, also you need to add `top: 0` if you want to stick to the top of the page

For example component

```
import { Component } from 'react';
import { Table } from 'antd';
import styles from "./styles.module.scss";

export default class TableSticky extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Table
        className={styles.table}
        columns={columns}
        dataSource={data}
        pagination={false}
      />
    )
  }
}
```

For example style

```
.table {
  & thead {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Also, I figured out that issue was not with ant version 3 actually, the issue is how our implementation was. Need to fix that.